# Understanding types in Haskell (lambda epxressions and higher order functions)

Tags: haskell

I'm currently doing a course in Haskell, and I have a lot of difficulty understanding the types of functions, particularly when there's function application or lambda expressions. Say for instance the following:

```
f = (\x -> \y -> \z -> [x (y z), y z])
```

or

```
g = \x -> \y -> \z -> x.y.z
```

I can sort of make some assumptions about the fact that `x` and `y` are functions, but I don't have a concrete method for figuring out the types of these functions.

Similarly for the following:

```
h = foldr (&&)
```

I try to guess and then check via `:t` in the interpreter, but I'm usually off by quite a bit.
Is there any particular method I can use to find the types of such functions?

Answer (score 4):

You start by assigning type variables to the inputs and the result

```
f = (\x -> \y -> \z -> [x (y z), y z])
```

and conclude

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d   --  (A0)
-- or even (f is not needed)
\x -> \y -> \z -> [x (y z), y z] :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

that is

```
x :: a                -- (1)
y :: b                -- (2)
z :: c                -- (3)
[x (y z), y z] :: d   -- (4)
```

You can continue with `(4)` and conclude

- that the type `d` is a list of `d1`s, i.e. `d ~ [d1]  (5)`

  ```
  f :: a -> b -> c -> [d1] -- (A1)
  ```
- and that the values of the list are of type `d1`, i.e.

  ```
  x (y z) :: d1  -- (6)
  y z :: d1      -- (7)
  ```

From `(6)` you learn that

```
x :: e -> d1   -- (8)
y z :: e       -- (9)
```

`(1)` and `(8)` unify, i.e. `a ~ (e -> d1)` and

```
f :: (e -> d1) -> b -> c -> [d1] -- (A2)
```

You play this game until you get bored and use `GHCi` to arrive at

```
f :: (d1 -> d1) -> (f -> d1) -> f -> [d1] -- (A3)
-- and renaming
f :: (a -> a) -> (b -> a) -> b -> [a]     -- (A4)
```

If you want to learn more and read a paper you can start with [Principal type-schemes for functional programs](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ecs4536/c12/milner-damas_principal_types.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
Prelude> :t h
h :: Foldable t => Bool -> t Bool -> Bool
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
Prelude> :t (&&)
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
Prelude>
```

By "plugging in" (&&) you have removed `(a -> b -> b)`
so you need to provide the rest to the function

```
b -> t a -> b
```

That is restricted by `(&&)` to be a bool as second param to it, and the second parameter is the `t a` which is also restricted to being a bool. since a and b needs to be the same type as in the `(a->b->b)` function.